# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'FabricName' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, workbench

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tailor`.`Fabric` (
 'FabricID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
 `type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `Color` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `FabricsTypeID` INT NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`FabricID`) ,
   REFERENCES `tailor`.`FabricsType` (`FabricsTypeID` )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

I always get this error Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'FabricsTypeID' in 'field list'(
  when I insert these codes:

```
Insert Into Fabrics('FabricID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Color','FabricsTypeID') values
('FB001','Black','cotton pants','black','FT001'),
('FB002','Dark Navy','cotton pants','Navy ','FT002'),
('FB003','White','cotton pants','White','FT013'),
('FB004','Dark Olive','cotton pants','Olive','FT004'),
('FB005','Navy','cotton pants','Navy ','FT005'),
('FB006','Brown','cotton pants','Brown','FT006'),
('FB007','Beige','cotton pants','Beige ','FT007'),
('FB008','Gray Blue','cotton pants','Gray Blue','FT008'),
('FB009','Dark Grey White Stripes','wool poly pants','Grey','FT001');
```

Comment: How are you running the insert? through an IDE? through your code?

Comment: no through workbench @JayBlanchard

Comment: Which error are you getting? The one in your title or the one in your post?

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'FabricsTypeID' in 'field list'
@SebastianPaaskeTørholm

Comment: i dont see this column `FabricsType_FabricsTypeID` defined in your table?

Comment: Is there any other code in Workbench? Is this part of a group of queries?

Comment: @cableload just edited the code

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes it is a database, with other tables

Comment: FabricsTypeID is defined as Integer, but it is being passed string values in your insert

Comment: If it is a script with other tables we need to isolate the table and query having `FabricsTypeID` as a column. The info you've posted here seems to not be relevant to the error.

Comment: @cableload can I add a varchar to a primary key

Comment: Yeah you can as long as its unique and its makes sense in the context of that table

Answer (score 0):

The table you're trying to insert into in your insert query is the table `Fabrics`, whereas the table you're creating in your create table query is the table `tailor.Fabric`.

Perhaps you have an old table by the name of `Fabrics`?

Comment: What a super catcher!